# Do check-in staff at airports generally have contacts for travel document verification if in doubt?

Tags: airports, paperwork, check-in

Check-in staff checking in passengers on flights to Australia have an Australian contact called BOC whom they can call in case of doubts regarding a passenger's travel documentation.

Does check-in staff usually have similar contacts in other countries as well? Of particular interest are Russia and Turkey

Comment: Airlines in the USA generally do.

Comment: There are at least 150 countries with an airport and hundreds of airlines between them. I'm sure there are way too many arrangements to cover in one answer.

Comment: How would the Bank of China help with Australian Visas?  ;)